# angularJs - bind same dataset to two <select> elements, one with default value and the other without

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, default-value

I have a dataset in angular where I add a default value as follows:

```js
            vm.serviceProperties.serviceCategories = clientcontext.clientlookup.serviceCategoryLookups();
            vm.serviceProperties.serviceCategories.splice(0, 0, { 'serviceCategoryId': 0, 'serviceCategoryDisplayName': 'All' });
```

I need to bind this dataset to two select controls. For one, I need to show the 'All' value as default. For the other, I don't need the 'All' value at all.

How can I achieve that with the same dataset? I remember I saw somewhere that without defining the default value in the dataset itself, we can create an element option within the . Something like below:

```html
<select>
  <option> default</option>
  <option ng-repeat="the dataset"></option>
</select>
```

But I'm not sure how to do it correct.

Comment: You could add a property to the controller scope that determines whether or not we display the `default` option?  Something like `$scope.showDefault = true;` and modify `<option> default</option>` to be `<option ng-if='showDefault'> default</option>`. Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property on the controllers that determines whether the default option is displayed or not.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('servicePropertiesWithDefault', function() {
    $scope.showDefault = true;
});

app.controller('servicePropertiesWithoutDefault', function() {
    $scope.showDefault = false;
});
```

Then in the template we use `ng-if` to show or hide the `default` option by passing in `showDefault` as the expression.  Using `ng-if` is better than `ng-show` as it removes the element from the DOM.

**Template**

```
<select>
  <option ng-if='showDefault'> default</option>
  <option ng-repeat="the dataset"></option>
</select>
```